# AzureのVirtual Machinesで立ち上げたCentOS上の仮想IPに他のサーバからアクセス出来ない。

Tags: centos, azure

お世話になります。

Azure上で2台のCentOS7を起動し、片方に下記コマンドで仮想IPを付与しました。

```
ip addr add $_IP_$/24 dev eth0 label eth0:1
```

ifconfig上ではeth0:1にIPが付与され、自身からはpingが届くのですが、
他のサーバからはpingが届きません。

※サブネット範囲内です。
※他のサーバからeth0にはpingが届きます。

仮想IPが付与出来ない、仕様なのでしょうか？ご存じの方、ご教示下さい。

Answer (score 1):

OS 側に複数の IP アドレスを付与したいのであれば、Azure 側のネットワークインターフェースにも IP アドレスを付与してください。

参考：
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-portal

Azure の仮想ネットワークが認識できるアドレスは Azure 側のネットワークインターフェースに付与されたものだけです。OS 側だけに IP アドレスを付与した場合、仮想ネットワークはこの IP アドレスの存在を認識できませんので、この IP アドレス宛てのパケットを転送しません。結果として OS 側だけに設定されている IP アドレスへの Ping が失敗します。